# regular expression select everything after word

Tags: regex

I am trying to select everything after CORP ACT OPTION NO. however my regular expression stops after it meets a /

My reg expression atm to extract the info is CORP ACT OPTION NO.([^/]*)

```
CORP ACT REFERENCE                  : 007XS0212069115
SENDER'S REFERENCE                  : 1212070800330001
FUNCTION OF MESSAGE                 : NEW MESSAGE
CORP ACT EVENT                      : INTEREST PAYMENT
PLACE OF SAFEKEEPING                : US
ISIN                                : XS0212069115
ISIN/DESCRIPTION                    : KFW 4.750 071212 GBP
METHOD OF INTEREST COMPUTATION      : A006
EX-DATE                             : 20121207
RECORD DATE                         : 20121206
CORP ACT OPTION NO.                 : 001
CORPORATE ACTION OPTION CODE        : CASH
CURRENCY OPTION                     : GBP
RESULTING AMT                       : GBP617,5
PAYMENT DATE                        : 20121207
EXCHANGE RATE                       : GBP/GBP/1,
INTEREST RATE                       : 4,75

SAFEKEEPING ACCOUNT                 : 000000000000
CONFIRMED BALANCE                   : FAMT/13000,
CREDIT/DEBIT IND                    : CREDIT
```

How can I select everything? Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `\s\S` in the character group:

```
CORP ACT OPTION NO\.([\s\S]*)
```

See it here in action: http://regexr.com?33vd0

Comment: This only selects one line?

Comment: how can I select all lines after with your reg expressioN?

Comment: Your top reg expression only matches until the end of the line